# How to create a new dataframe from another frame with list as columns in the original df?

Tags: python, dataframe

How to create a new dataframe from another frame with list as columns in the original df?

```
**org_df**

   heading   value
0  newspaper   ['nytime','chicago tribute','usa today','wsl]
1  tv                                          ['cnn,'cbs']



**new_df**

| heading  | items             |
| -------- | ----------------- |
| newspaper| nytime            |
| newspaper| chicago tribute   |
| newspaper| usa today         |
| newspaper| wsl               |
| tv       | cnn               |
| tv       | cbs               |
```

Comment: You can use `df.pivot`

Comment: Would you mind sharing the original DataFrame instead of typing it?

Comment: @Luke, how can I do that?

Comment: Copy the DataFrame from Pandas and Paste it here on Stack Overflow

Comment: @Luke, I update the posting.  will that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
new_df = org_df.explode('value', ignore_index=True)
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
    heading               value
0   newspaper            nytime
1   newspaper   chicago tribute
2   newspaper         usa today
3   newspaper               wsl
4   tv                      cnn
5   tv                      cbs
```

Optionally, if you want to rename the column `value` to `items`:

```
new_df = new_df.rename({'value': 'items'}, axis='columns')
```

Comment: This works!  Thanks!  I need to look into ignore_index a bit to get exactly what I need.

Comment: it renumbers the index to 0, 1, 2, ...5 instead of showing 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1

Comment: heading is the original index.  I need to keep that.  ```    new_df = df.explode('value', ignore_index=False)
    new_df.index.name = 'heading'
    new_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    print(new_df[['heading', 'value']])```